# Logitech Speakers Constantly Cutting Out

Tags: speakers

Recently, I installed a set of Logitech Z333 speakers by my desk. I've had these speakers for roughly a year now and they've never done what I'm about to describe until I started using them with my pc. This set of speakers has 2 small speakers and a subwoofer.

While I'm playing music, a video game, or any constant sound at all, the speakers randomly cut out for random amounts of time (usually 5-10 seconds). I haven't heard any specific pattern to when they cut out, they just seem to do it whenever they want. I've already looked for drivers to fix this problem (found none) and I've also checked that the connections are good. The problem is this: The speakers use an AUX cord to connect to my PC, and when that AUX cord is plugged in, any playing sound I have, whether its coming from my headphones, monitor speakers, or these speakers, cut out randomly as well. But, when I unplug the AUX cord, the cutting out stops for my headphones and monitor speakers.

Is this something wrong with my speakers? Or is there a driver that I need to get that I'm clueless about? I'm running my PC on windows 10 with no drivers.

Comment: O/T. Most likely faulty motherboard in the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I figured out that the issue only kicked in when the subwoofer was in use. I found that it was an improperly seated connector going into the subwoofer. I reoriented the connector until the issue stopped. I don't know if that's your issue, but I'm just replying because there are like no threads on this topic online that actually have resolutions.